# How to explain Chinese remainder theorem?

Tags: algebra, teaching, terminology

I want to explain Chinese remainder theorem to master level computer science students. There are two versions of CRT one is number theoretic and second requires the definition of ideals, groups etc. Although students know about these definitions, but I think I should explain these definitions again.

My question is from where I should start and how to motivate them. Should I start with examples or first definition and then example. What are the good examples I should give them. I don't want to confuse my students with lots of symbols and notation. Please note that target audience is master level computer science students.

The name of the course is Algebraic Computation, it is mostly related computational group theory etc.

Comment: A good example to start with and to motivate can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem and also here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinesischer_Restsatz (German, but look at the mathematics).

Comment: Why do they need to know this? What specific applications do you want to explain to them, if any? Answer this and I think you'll make progress on answering your own question.

Comment: It would be better to call the result "Sun-Ze's theorem", rather than the somewhat bizarre-ethnocentric "Chinese remainder theorem", I think.

Comment: Do you need to cover the "ideals" version of the theorem? Unless the students are unusually smart **and** unusually theoretically-oriented, I'd just forget that I ever heard of ideals and teach the number-theoretic version (starting with Fizz-Buzz as in some comments under Adam's answer).

Answer (score 2):

I would start with motivation first. Since these are CS students, it should be an application. You can use anything that would broadly be considered useful. (i.e. not minutiae of your research.) Motivate why you would like a theorem like the CRT before you state it.

Do a few toy cases visually. For example, here are residues modulo 3 and 5:

[image: residues modulo 3 and 5]

and here are residues modulo 3 and 6:

[image: residues modulo 3 and 6]

Note that not all of the latter's lattice points are hit.

After that, you can dive into computational aspects. Avoid the version with ideals until the end; if you can get them to understand the usual version of the CRT, the principle ideal version should be a homework exercise. i.e. once you know what it means for two ideals to be relatively prime, the proof looks identical to the usual one.

Comment: Could you please explain the diagrams you drew?

Comment: I expanded on the explanation so that it hopefully explains the diagrams more clearly now.

Comment: Can these examples be tied to the "FizzBuzz" computer programming exercise?

Comment: @Magne I have rejected this edit because it corrected no errors and, quite honestly, you made it sound like I didn't know what the CRT was.

Comment: @Jasper FizzBuzz is defined terms of modular arithmetic with primes 3 and 5, so: yes!

Comment: @Adam I ask you to reconsider. After "It would be nice to have a theorem that would ...", I did include: "CRT is precisely that theorem". So think its obvious to readers that you do know what the CRT is. I actually did it to be in line with your intention of motivating (the students) as to why we would like a theorem such as the CRT. I think the added explanation (however trivial sounding) would help newcomers to understand the diagrams. Because I sure spent quite a bit of time trying to understand them, in and of themselves, even though I understood CRT beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that these CS students know how to encrypt using RSA.  It can be shown that combining RSA with the Chinese Remainder Theorem can speed up the decryption of messages.  This might be good motivation with a CS focus.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it partially answer my question but if possible add more content to the answer to make a full answer.